# overloading the >> operator

Tags: c++, input, operator-overloading

I am having trouble, in fact i am stuck.I have to define a class for rational numbers.now part of it is to overload both the input and output operators, now i have done it for the output operator but I am stuck with the input. 
this is as far as i got upto the point where I got stuck

```
    istream& operator >>(istream& ins, rational& frac)
{
    int numerator, denominator;
    ins >> numerator;
    if()
    return ins;
}
```

my question is how do I make them seperate the numerator and denominator. my class header is as follows if it will help.

```
#ifndef RAT_H
#define RAT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class rational
{
    public:
        rational();
        rational(int n,int d);
        rational(int whole_number);
        friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const rational& frac);
        friend istream& operator >>(istream& ins, rational& frac);
    private:
        void split(string fract);
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
        string farray[2];
        string fraction;
};

#endif // RAT_H
```

the output opperator does this:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const rational& frac)
{
    outs << frac.numerator<<'/'<<frac.denominator;
    return outs;
}
```

Comment: Well, I would expect the input and output operators to be inverses of each other, but inconveniently you have not said what the output operator does.

Comment: I have edited it to include the output operator

Answer (score 3):

All you really need to do is

1. Read the numerator
2. If that's successful, see if the next character is a `'/'` and, if so, `ignore()` it.
3. Read the denominator.
4. Set the value.

So, all it really takes is

```
int numerator, denominator;
if (in >> numerator
    && (in >> std::ws).peek() == '/'
    && in.ignore() >> denominator) {
    ...
}
```

The only tricky business is the use of `std::ws` which will skip whitespace if any. It isn't really needed for your format.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really gone into enough detail as to what you are
willing to accept as input, but the usual solution for handling
separators is to define a manipulator which picks them up, and
sets `failbit` if they are absent.  Something like:

```
class CheckedSeparator
{
    char m_separ;
public:
    CheckedSeparator( char separ ) : m_separ( separ ) {}
    friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& source, 
                                     CheckedSeparator const& dest )
    {
        char separSeen;
        source >> separSeen;
        if ( separSeen != dest.m_separ ) {
            source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
        }
        return source;
    }
};
```

If you do this, there's no need for `if`:

```
std::istream&
operator>>( std::istream& source, Rational& frac )
{
    int n;
    int d;
    source >> n >> CheckedSeparator('/') >> d;
    if ( source ) {
        frac = Rational( n, d );
    }
    return source;
}
```

Comment: oh sorry I have to input a fraction like 12/2. so what you wrote is fine